# streamlining generic property creation

Tags: python, oop, properties

I'm new to Python and I find that when making classes I keep having to write

```
@property
def example(self):
    return self._example

@example.setter
def example(self, example):
     if #some conditions here:
          self._example = example
```

I am working on a project and there are over a dozen of these across it, so I tried to make a function that would take a property name and some conditions and make a getter, setter and deleter for it.

```
class Util:

    @classmethod
    def custom_property(cls, prop, conds=None, deletable=False):
        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, f'_{prop}')

        def setter(self, value):
            if conds is None or conds(value):
                setattr(self, f'_{prop}', value)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid value for {prop}')

        def deleter(self):
            if deletable:
                del self._value
            else:
                print("This attribute can't be deleted.")

        # setattr(target, prop, property(getter, setter, deleter))

        return [getter, setter, deleter]
```

and here is an example of me trying to use it:

```
from utils import Util

def name_conds(name):
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError("City name must be a string")
    if not name.strip():
        raise ValueError("City name cannot be blank")
    if not 2 <= len(name) <= 25:
        raise ValueError("City name length must be between 2 and 25 characters")
    return True

class City:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    [name_getter, name_setter, name_deleter] = Util.custom_property("name", name_conds)
    name = property(name_getter, name_setter, name_deleter)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't totally work. If I make a city with a name "asdf" and try to change it to "a", I get the right error that the length is wrong, but if I instantiate a new city with a name "a", I am allowed to with no problem. Surely there is some way people have gotten around writing properties out like I have? Also, as the commented line in Util shows, I wanted to be able to use the method in a quicker way by just calling Util.custom_property inside whatever class needed a property, but that added the property to Util (of course, since it is adding it to cls). It seems there is no way to give the class City as an argument inside City, but then calling custom_property outside of city might mean the functions in city can't reference name properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with your property, but with the fact that you aren't *using* the property in `City.__init__`. `_name` is really a private implementation detail of the property itself (though the value is stored on the instance of `City`), so `City` methods should not use it directly, either.

---

While I'm answering the question, I'll point out that `custom_property` doesn't have to be a class method (or a method of any class); it can be an ordinary function. Further, it can return a `property` instance itself that you can assign directly to an attribute of `City`. Finally, you can optimize `setter` by defining one that unconditionally sets the value if `conds` is `None`, and you can just omit the deleter if `deletable` is `False`.

```
def custom_property(cls, prop, conds=None, deletable=False):
    name = f'_{prop}'

    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, name)

    if conds is None:
        def setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, name, value)
    else:
        def setter(self, value):
            if conds(value):
                setattr(self, name, value)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid value for {prop}')

    if deletable:
        def deleter(self):
            delattr(self, name)
    else:
        deleter = None

    return property(getter, setter, deleter)
```

Then

```
from utils import custom_property


def name_conds(name):
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError("City name must be a string")
    if not name.strip():
        raise ValueError("City name cannot be blank")
    if not 2 <= len(name) <= 25:
        raise ValueError("City name length must be between 2 and 25 characters")
    return True


class City:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Use the property, not _name

    name = custom_property("name", name_conds)
```

Comment: If you want another challenge, try defining `custom_property` as a descriptor  that defines `__set_name__` as well, so you don't need to pass the name of the property as an explicit argument: `name = custom_property(name_conds)`.

Comment: i took the challenge

Comment: Another challenge -- get type hinting/static type checking to work with `custom_property`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly i think that can only be done by implementing all this logic in a standalone descriptor class. Because `property` is not generic...

Comment: `property` is not generic, but there is special handling for it so that, for example, the static type of `City("stockholm").name` is whatever the return type of the getter is.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure the handling of `property` is *heavily* specialized by IDE type hinting and static type checkers. I believe `Enum` (it has `name` and `value` properties, which are actually `DynamicClassAttributes`) gets around this by [shadowing the builtins `property`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6aadabcfe667d1ad292ce04a9263b500ea74fb6e/Lib/enum.py#L184), I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addition to @chepner's answer.

I didn't like the fact that the "name" is repeated. There is a way for python to use the name of the property.

```py
class City:
    ...
    name = custom_property("name", name_conds)
    # ^ we can take this "name" and pass it to your property
```

But for this to work we need a custom property that accepts the name:

```py
class AutoNameProperty(property):
    def __set_name__(self, cls, name):
        self.name = name
```

The `__set_name__` is called by python for all objects inside a class. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#customized-names) for more information

The `custom_property` then has to use the name instead of the parameter:

```py
def custom_property(conds=None, deletable=False):
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, f'_{p.name}')  # use p.name instead of parameter

    def setter(self, value):
        if ...
            setattr(self, f'_{p.name}', value)  # use p.name instead of parameter
        ...

    ...

    # it is necessary to assign this to a name, so the functions can use it
    p = AutoNameProperty(getter, setter, deleter)
    return p
```

The usage is then even simpler:

```py
class City:
    ...

    name = custom_property(name_conds)
```

**Edit: Because it was requested, here is a version with type hints**

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from collections.abc import Callable

T = TypeVar('T')


class MyProperty(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, typ: type[T], conditions: Callable[[T], bool] | None = None) -> None:
        self.name = ''
        self.conditions = conditions
        self.type = typ

    def __set_name__(self, cls: type[object], name: str) -> None:
        self.name = f'_{name}'

    def __get__(self, instance: object, cls: type[object]) -> T:
        assert instance is not None  # or do the overload for instance = None

        value = getattr(instance, self.name)
        assert isinstance(value, self.type)  # surprisingly mypy is smart enough and knows that value is a T after that
        return value

    def __set__(self, instance: object, value: T) -> None:
        if self.conditions and not self.conditions(value):
            raise ValueError
        setattr(instance, self.name, value)
```

Use it like this:

```py
class City:
    name = MyProperty(str, name_conds)
```

Comment: Oh, nice, it didn't occur to me to make the getter et al refer back to the property itself like that.

Comment: But partial credit only for having a separate function and subclass of `property` :)

Comment: @chepner I spent the past 30min to track down what happens when `property`'s `__set_name__` is called. Because that method exists and apparently a `__name__` attribute also exists, but in python it always throws `AttributeError`. It's really mysterious

Comment: So in your example, the `AutoNameProperty` gets created by and return from `custom_property`. That object gets assigned to the name `name` in the (temporary) namespace created by the `class` statement. Once the whole body has been evaluate, that namespace is passed to the `__prepare__` method of the metaclass, and I think *that* is what calls `__set_name__` for each descriptor it finds that has said method.

Comment: I have a small working example, and can't reproduce the error. Is your `AttributeError` raised by/from `__set_name__`, or later? (Did you remember to define `City.__init__` to assign a value to `self.name`?)

Comment: The attribute error is raised when i access `City.name.__name__`. That attribute should exist, if i understand the source code of `PyProperty_Type` correctly

Comment: `City.name` is the property; it doesn't have a `__name__` attribute (or at least, not one that you can about or exists outside the C implementation). You just access `name` from the object as normal, e.g. `City("Rome").name == "Rome"`.

Comment: I think the type-hinted version is too complicated; think more how dataclasses specify types. You just specify annotations, rather than pass type objects as runtime arguments.