# How to generate crud methods for flask_restful resource classes

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm trying to create some routing for my server and have found that I am repeating myself a lot when defining the methods for the classes that bridge my React requests and Flask SQLAlchemy models. Here is an example of some of the resources and the repetitive functions:

```
class Users(Resource):

    def get(self):
        #this might work to exclude passwords
        users = [user.to_dict(rules=("-password",)) for user in User.query.all()]
        return make_response(jsonify(users), 200)
    
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()

        try:
            new_user = User(
                name = data['name'],
                password = data['password']
            )
        except:
            error = {"errors": ["validation errors"]}
            return make_response(jsonify(error), 400)
        
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return make_response(new_user.to_dict(), 201)
    
api.add_resource(Users, '/users')

class UserByID(Resource):
        
    def get(self, id):
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first().to_dict()
        if user:
            return make_response(jsonify(user), 200)
        error = {"error": "User not found"}
        return make_response(jsonify(error), 404)

    def patch(self, id):
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        for attr in request.json:
            setattr(user, attr, request.json[attr])

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return make_response(user.to_dict(), 202)

api.add_resource(UserByID, '/users/<int:id>')

class Prompts(Resource):

    def get(self):
        prompts = [prompt.to_dict() for prompt in Prompt.query.all()]
        return make_response(jsonify(prompts), 200)
    
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()

        try:
            new_prompt = Prompt(
                title = data['title'],
                content = data['content'],
                user_id = data['user_id']
            )
        except:
            error = {"errors": ["validation errors"]}
            return make_response(jsonify(error), 400)
        
        db.session.add(new_prompt)
        db.session.commit()

        return make_response(new_prompt.to_dict(), 201)
    
api.add_resource(Prompts, '/prompts')

class PromptByID(Resource):

    def get(self, id):
        prompt = Prompt.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        return make_response(jsonify(prompt), 200)

    def patch(self, id):
        prompt = Prompt.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        for attr in request.json:
            setattr(prompt, attr, request.json[attr])

        db.session.add(prompt)
        db.session.commit()

        return make_response(prompt.to_dict(), 202)

api.add_resource(PromptByID, '/prompts/<int:id>')
```

I was thinking of approaching the problem [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78094327/streamlining-generic-property-creation) but haven't been able to get very far. The method will probably have to be supplied the name of the Model like User or Prompt. I also saw something about creating class decorators, but I'm not sure that would work since I imagine I'd have to use one decorator to make several methods.

Comment: Also you need to take into account which fields are compulsory and which are not, additional changes which may need to be triggered by a certain create/update/delete, non-standard data (such as file uploads) etc. For this purpose, creating a fully standardized way of handling requests is not a good practice. I have done it by implementing like 10 layers of abstraction which sacrificed performance and readability of the code. I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: Have you looked at [Flask-Muck](https://github.com/dtiesling/flask-muck)?